# Cant Remove Items From Shopping Cart React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm implementing the shopping cart feature in my React and Redux app, and now I'm facing the problem with removing all items of one type from the cart. When I click on a button to remove an item from the cart, instead of removing it, it clears my whole cart.

I have my reducer function:

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload),
      };
    case CART_REMOVE_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product !== action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And my action

```
export const removeProductFromCart = (product) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CART_REMOVE_PRODUCT,
    payload: product,
  });

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

In the end, there In my component, I have a function where I dispatch an action

```
  const removeFromCartHandler = (item) => {
    dispatch(removeProductFromCart(item._id));
  };
```

Which is called inside a button like this
`onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item)}`

An item is an object in a row, and it has its id

I hope someone can see where am I making a mistake. Thank you all.

Comment: What's the output when you `console.log(x.product,action.payload)` ?

Comment: Isn't it `state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product._id !== action.payload)`

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress x.product is my id, or cartItem.product in my case

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I tried cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((cartItem) =>
          console.log(cartItem.product, action.payload)
        ),
      }; and console gave me undefined unfefined

Comment: @seven yeah so that's the issue. Check whether the property you're accessing on the concerned objects even exists or not.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur, yeah, if I change my cartItem.product to cartItem.id, I got the id of my product, but action.payload is still undefined

Comment: @seven so that maybe because you're passing `item._id` when it should be `item.id` ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Thank you, my man! I lost myself with .id and ._id